# ng-animate does not work with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, ng-animate

I want my navigation items to be animated when i change the navigation, hence am using 'ng-animate', but no effect is being applied.

Here is my code,

**HTML:**

```
 <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-animate="'animate'" ng-repeat="widget in Widgets | filter : selected">
       <div layout="row" layout-margin> 
          <div flex="60">
             <img ng-src="{{widget.icon}}" class="md-avatar" alt="{{widget.title}}"> 
                <div class="md-list-item-text">
                <h4>{{ widget.title }}</h4>
                <h5>{{ widget.Description }}</h5>
           </div>
        </div>
       <div flex="20">
      <md-button style="width:100px"    class="md-raised">Add</md-button>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/1GnkdUo79QF5hJuOVoWU?p=preview) for the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking into animations with `md-list` today. I simplified your code and adjusted the layout to get it to work. I also updated to latest material and angular 1.4.1.

This should be enough to get u started: http://plnkr.co/edit/y1SClyHOT2GEnXvdhvlf?p=preview

Comment: Yea, sorry something got messed up, should work now.